# Opengles How to change black pixels to transparent pixels

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

My code is

```
vec4 textureColor = texture2D(uTextureSampler, vTextureCoord);
if(textureColor.r* 0.299 + textureColor.g * 0.587 + textureColor.b * 0.114 < 0.1) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
} else {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.r, textureColor.g, textureColor.b, textureColor.w);
}
```

My problem is how to judge the pixel is black? How can I do that, should change rgb to hsv?

Comment: @BDL yes, Forgive my poor English

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be working with that code. If `textureColor` is [0,0,0], then you definitely end up with a transparent pixel. (Assuming the there is no problem in the rest of your OpenGL application). What happens if you unconditionally output `gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);`?

Comment: `if(textureColor.r* 0.299 + textureColor.g * 0.587 + textureColor.b * 0.114 < 0.1)` is judge black pixel, if is black pixel, i change this pixel to transparent, so `gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);` is change the pixel to transparent

Comment: The method to judge the pixel color is not correct, and some dark blue can be judged black

Answer (score 0):

```
        return "precision mediump float; \n"+
            "   varying highp vec2 " + VARYING_TEXTURE_COORD + ";\n" +
            "   \n" +
            "   uniform sampler2D " + TEXTURE_SAMPLER_UNIFORM + ";\n" +
            "   \n" +
            " void main()\n" +
            " {\n" +
            " vec3 keying_color = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);\n" +
            " float thresh = 0.45; // [0, 1.732]\n" +
            " float slope = 0.1; // [0, 1]\n" +
            " vec3 input_color = texture2D(" + TEXTURE_SAMPLER_UNIFORM + ", " + VARYING_TEXTURE_COORD + ").rgb;\n" +
            " float d = abs(length(abs(keying_color.rgb - input_color.rgb)));\n" +
            " float edge0 = thresh * (1.0 - slope);\n" +
            " float alpha = smoothstep(edge0, thresh, d);\n" +
            " gl_FragColor = vec4(input_color,alpha);\n" +
            " }";
```

In the keying_color variable is stored the actual color we want to replace. It is using classic RGB model, but intensity is not expressed as 0-255 integer. It is a float value in range 0-1. (So 0 = 0, 255 = 0, 122 = 0.478…) In our case, the green color has value (0.647, 0.941, 0.29), but if you are using different video, measure the color yourself.
Note: Make sure you have the right color. Some color measurement software automatically converts colors to slightly different formats, such as AdobeRGB.
So where’s the magic?
We load current pixel color in the input_color, then calculate difference between input and keying color. Based on this difference, alpha value is calculated and used for specific pixel.
You can control how strict the comparison is using the slope and threshold values. It is a bit more complicated, but the most basic rule is: The more threshold you have, the bigger tolerance.
So, we are done, right? Nope.

You can look this link: http://blog.csdn.net/u012847940/article/details/47441923